# SAS - Fill values for each group

Tags: sas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Stop    Group
JFK     A
JFK     B
JFK     C
AMS     A
AMS     B
AMS     C
LHR     A
SFO     B
```

I'm trying to generate a new data set where each `Stop` will have values A, B and C. For example, JFK and AMS already have A-C, so no change is needed. LHR needs B and C added and SFO needs A and C added. The output dataset should look like this:

```
JFK A
JFK B
JKF C
AMS A
AMS B
AMS C
LHR A
LHR B
LHR C
SFO A
SFO B
SFO C
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is commonly asked on here and in general. You can search PRELOADFMT for several options and apporaches. The SPARSE option on PROC FREQ is another method. You also need to include anything you've tried so far, so if you're having issues with a specific approach we can help out.

Comment: @natnay can you confirm if that solution was useful in solving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple quick solution:

> ```
> PROC SQL noprint;
>   select distinct quote(stop) into :stop separated by ', '
>   from have;
>   select distinct quote(group) into :group separated by ', '
>   from have;
> quit;
>
> data want;
>   length stop $4 Group $2;
>   do stop=&stop.;
>     do Group=&group.;
>       output;
>     end;
>   end;
> run;
> ```